# compiler is not able to find the given paths

Tags: c++, qt, .profile

I have included the headers in Qt for my project, but the compiler is still not able to identify the headers. Libraries once included created its own includepath and depend.

Any help appriciated:

```
`INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../HDE/x86.linux/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../HDE/x86.linux/include

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../HDE/x86.linux/lib/ -lddskernel

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../HDE/x86.linux/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../HDE/x86.linux/include

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../HDE/x86.linux/examples/dcps/Tutorial/cpp/standalone/ -lsacpp_tutorial_types

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../HDE/x86.linux/examples/dcps/Tutorial/cpp/standalone
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../HDE/x86.linux/examples/dcps/Tutorial/cpp/standalone

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/ -lpthread

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to do is also include the path for the header files in .pro file. 
for instance if the header file is at location /home/jack/Myproject
then just write the below in the .pro file

INCLUDEPATH +=$$PWD/../Myproject